# Parameters in a stored procedure vba

Tags: vba, stored-procedures, parameters

I have some problems with my code :

```
Dim title, datee As String
Dim ConnectionString As String
Dim sPassword As String
Dim sUser As String
Dim sDatabase As String
Dim sServer As String
Dim req As String
Dim Cmd1  As New ADODB.Command
Dim AConn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim Rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim dateee As Date
dateee = "2013-10-10"
Dim prm As ADODB.Parameter

title = Cells(1, 6).Value
datee = Cells(2, 4).Value
Range("A6:Z65500").ClearContents

title = Left(title, Len(title) - 10) + datee
Cells(1, 6).Value = title
sServer = Worksheets("BaseDeDonnees").Cells(3, 3)
sDatabase = Worksheets("BaseDeDonnees").Cells(4, 3)
sUser = Worksheets("BaseDeDonnees").Cells(5, 3)
sPassword = Worksheets("BaseDeDonnees").Cells(6, 3)

AConn.ConnectionString = "UID=" & sUser & ";PWD=" & sPassword & ";" & "DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=" & sServer & ";Database=" & sDatabase & ";"
AConn.Open

Cmd1.ActiveConnection = AConn
Cmd1.CommandText = "test"
Cmd1.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

Set prm = Cmd1.CreateParameter("@dateMax", adDBTimeStamp, adParamInput)
Cmd1.Parameters.Append prm
Cmd1.Parameters("@dateMax").Value = dateee

Set prm = Cmd1.CreateParameter("@usrID", adInteger, adParamInput)
Cmd1.Parameters.Append prm
Cmd1.Parameters("@usrID").Value = 100768

Cmd1.Execute
AConn.Close
```

I have an error message : procedure or function 'test' expects parameter '@usrID', which was not supplied. I really dont know why i have this error, @usrID, is defined...
Can you help me ? Thanks :)

Comment: `CreateParameter("dateMax"`...? then `prm.Value = datee`?

Answer (score 0):

Any parameters I've passed to a stored-procedure (at least for SQL Server), I've passed in as I've created the parameter.  So in your case I would do so as follows:

```
Set prm = Cmd1.CreateParameter("@usrID", adInteger, adParamInput, 4, 100768)
Cmd1.Parameters.Append prm
```

or if you are lazy like me:

```
Cmd1.Parameters.Append Cmd1.CreateParameter("@usrID", adInteger, adParamInput, 4, 100768)
```

Note, the second last parameter is the size of the input in bytes or for strings (varchars) length and the last parameter is the value being passed.

More info here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677209%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the answer, unfortunately i tried this before, and it didnt work... I have the same error message with these lines :
Cmd1.Parameters.Append Cmd1.CreateParameter("@dateMax", adDBTimeStamp, adParamInput, 0, dateee) 
Cmd1.Parameters.Append Cmd1.CreateParameter("@usrID", adInteger, adParamInput, 10, 100768) I'll see you link.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:

```
Cmd1.NamedParameters = True
```

before assigning the parameters, otherwise they're actually being passed by position.